# Doctrine wrong results when using NOT IN with Postgresql and Symfony 4.4

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine, dql

I have 3 tables: contact, mailing_list and mailing_list_contact. Each contact can be subscribed to multiple mailing lists, recorded in mailing_list_contact.

To fetch the total contact count subscribed to a mailing list i use this query:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('contact')
->select('count(distinct contact.id)')
->leftJoin('contact.mailingListContacts', 'mlc')
->leftJoin('mlc.mailingList', 'ml')
->andWhere('ml IN (:mailingList)')
->setParameter('mailingList', $mailingList)
->getQuery()
->getSingleScalarResult();
```

This results in 7620 contacts and is correct.

When doing a NOT IN query, i get unexpected results and can not get my head around it. This is my NOT IN query which should return the contacts not subscribed to a single mailing list:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('contact')
->select('count(distinct contact.id)')
->leftJoin('contact.mailingListContacts', 'mlc')
->leftJoin('mlc.mailingList', 'ml')
->andWhere('ml NOT IN (:mailingList) or mlc.mailingList is null')
->setParameter('mailingList', $mailingList)
->getQuery()
->getSingleScalarResult();
```

This produces a contact count of 9064. The total contact count is 9109. I am expecting that this query would return 1489 contacts. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you remove the additional `or mlc.mailingList is null` clause?

Answer (score 0):

The query criteria `ml NOT IN (:mailingList) or mlc.mailingList is null` is retrieving the number of the contacts that are subscribed to any mailing list except those specified as well as those that are not subscribed to any mailing list.

### Dataset Criteria

The issue appears to be a misunderstanding of how SQL limits datasets based on the specified criteria(s).

Using `JOIN` in conjunction with a `WHERE` criteria on the `JOIN` table to limit the dataset, the database will first retrieve all matching records within the `JOIN` table prior to filtering them within the context of the `SELECT` table, which can lead to unexpected results. Additionally causing decreased performance when a significant amount of records are in the `JOIN` table.

Instead, the datasets can be limited for the `SELECT` and `JOIN` tables individually by specifying a criteria for each.
Appending the desired criteria to the `JOIN ON` clause using `AND` prevents unexpected results and improves performance by limiting the dataset of the join table, while also utilizing `INNER JOIN` when appropriate to further limit the dataset of the select table.

Use `INNER JOIN` to retrieve only the records that match.
Use `LEFT JOIN` to retrieve records regardless of if they match or not.

```
SELECT s.id 
FROM s 
INNER JOIN j 
ON j.s_id = s.id 
AND j.id = 1
```

### Doctrine DQL Functionality

The Doctrine ORM QueryBuilder produces DQL.

In DQL, add `WITH` to append the `AND` portion of the criteria to the automatically referenced `JOIN ON` clause.

```
/* ORM QueryBuilder */
->leftJoin('Entity.association', 'a', 'WITH', 'a.property IN(:param)')

/* DQL */
LEFT JOIN Entity.association a WITH a.property IN(:param)

/* Resulting SQL */
LEFT JOIN association_table AS a
ON a.entity_id = entity.id
AND a.property IN(:param)
```

Additionally using `IDENTITY()` retrieves the associated Identity column without needing an additional `JOIN` to establish the relationship.

```
/* ORM QueryBuilder */
->leftJoin('Entity.association', 'a', 'WITH', 'IDENTITY(a.association) IN(:param)')

/* DQL */
LEFT JOIN Entity.association a WITH IDENTITY(a.association) IN(:param)

/* Resulting SQL */
LEFT JOIN association_table AS a
ON a.entity_id = entity.id
AND a.association_id IN(:param)
```

### Count Contacts subscribed to the specified mailing lists

[DB-Fiddle - Query #4](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2zgAK34fdJApJofLZpUVSn/1)

To determine the number of contacts subscribed to the specified mailing lists, limit the dataset of the contacts by using `INNER JOIN` and move the `WHERE` criteria to the `ON` clause.

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('contact')
    ->select('count(distinct contact.id)')
    /* retrieve only contact subscriptions with the specified mailing lists */
    ->innerJoin('contact.mailingListContacts', 'mlc', 'WITH', 'IDENTITY(mlc.mailingList) IN(:mailingList)')
    ->setParameter('mailingList', $mailingList);

/* Resulting SQL */
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT contact.id)
FROM contact
INNER JOIN mailingListContacts AS mlc 
ON mlc.contact_id = contact.id
AND mlc.mailing_list_id IN(:mailingList);
```

### Count Contacts without Subscriptions

[DB-Fiddle - Query #5](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2zgAK34fdJApJofLZpUVSn/1)

To determine the number of contacts that are not subscribed to any mailing list, an exclusion join can be used as `LEFT JOIN AS j WHERE j.s_id IS NULL` to retrieve the records that do not exist in the join table.

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('contact')
    ->select('count(distinct contact.id)')
    /* retrieve all contact subscriptions */
    ->leftJoin('contact.mailingListContacts', 'mlc')
    /* limit to only missing contacts */
    ->andWhere('mlc.contact is null');

/* Resulting SQL */
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT contact.id)
FROM contact
LEFT JOIN mailingListContacts AS mlc 
ON mlc.contact_id = contact.id
WHERE mlc.contact_id IS NULL;
```

### Count Contacts not subscribed to the specified mailing lists

[DB-Fiddle - Query #6](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2zgAK34fdJApJofLZpUVSn/1)

To determine the number of contacts that are not subscribed to specific mailing lists, expand the above exclusion join query by appending the criteria to the `JOIN ON` clause to limit the dataset of the join table to only the desired mailing lists to validate.

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('contact')
    ->select('count(distinct contact.id)')
    /* retrieve all contact subscriptions limited to only the specified mailing lists */
    ->leftJoin('contact.mailingListContacts', 'mlc', 'WITH', 'IDENTITY(mlc.mailingList) IN(:mailingLists)')
    /* limit to only missing contacts */
    ->andWhere('mlc.contact is null');

/* Resulting SQL */
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT contact.id)
FROM contact
LEFT JOIN mailingListContacts AS mlc 
ON mlc.contact_id = contact.id
AND mlc.mailing_list_id IN(:mailingList)
WHERE mlc.contact_id IS NULL;
```

### Count Contacts with subscriptions except the specified mailing lists

[DB-Fiddle - Query #7](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2zgAK34fdJApJofLZpUVSn/1)

To determine the number of contacts with subscriptions excluding the specified mailing lists, change the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`, as well as `IN()` to `NOT IN()`, and remove the `WHERE` clause.

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('contact')
    ->select('count(distinct contact.id)')
    /* retrieve all contact subscriptions not subscribed to the specified mailing lists */
    ->innerJoin('contact.mailingListContacts', 'mlc', 'WITH', 'IDENTITY(mlc.mailingList) NOT IN(:mailingLists)');

/* Resulting SQL */
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT contact.id)
FROM contact
INNER JOIN mailingListContacts AS mlc 
ON mlc.contact_id = contact.id
AND mlc.mailing_list_id NOT IN(:mailingList);
```